# TypeScript Definitions for Forge Viewer missing Profiles related typings

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using typescript definitions for Forge from the DefinitelyTyped repository: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/forge-viewer

but I'm missing a lot of typings, specefically those related with Profiles management:

```
viewer.registerProfile(...)
wiewer.setProfile(...)
constructor: Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(customProfileSettings...)
Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.AEC
Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.clone(...)
```

also need the function for setting FPSs:

```
viewer.impl.setFPSTargets(...)
```

I don't know how to declare them since even on the Autodesk's docs they are missing:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/TypeDefs/ProfileSettings/

Anybody has these types of some guidance (not too generalistic) of how to implement them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all functions or properties are declared in type definition, while you can add them, following their definition in viewer source. e.g. for setFPSTargets, the definition in viewer source is:

[image]

In Type, the declare could be:

[image]

the functions or properties in impl are not officially released, so they have not exposed on API help document.

Comment: Thanks @Xiaodong, that helps a lot. Upvoted, but I'll left the answer unchecked as correct for some days to see if somebody can bring the profile related function's definitions.

Comment: It seems nobody else knows about this... @Xiaodong_Liang, how must I create the typing? I mean, do I have to include namespace, class and all other methods of this just to type setFPSTargets?

Comment: Hi @Vi100, sorry I just noticed your update. Yes, in this case, topmost namespace(Autodesk), the class impl (Viewer3DImpl) has been available, so only add the method. you can see I put in the methods list of Viewer3DImpl.  If it does not work, please let us know.